# Setting value to objects' property from its function doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use `new_Color.next()` to each time it is called return a different color in array-order. But it always return `blue`. What did I wrong?

```
var new_Color = {
    index: 0,
    colors: ['blue', 'lightblue', 'darkblue'],
    next: function() {
        this.index = this.index + 1 < this.colors.length? 0: this.index + 1;
        return this.colors[this.index];
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change to this: `this.index = this.index + 1 >= this.colors.length? 0: this.index + 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're always resetting the `index` to `0` because `(0) + 1` is less than the `length`. Flip the comparison operator, and make it `length - 1`.

```
var new_Color = {
    index: 0,
    colors: ['blue', 'lightblue', 'darkblue'],
    next: function() {
        //                          v right here
        this.index = this.index + 1 > this.colors.length - 1 ? 0 : this.index + 1;
        return this.colors[this.index];
    }
};
```

If you want to start with `blue`, make your initial index `-1`.